# How to pass values of multiple checkboxes to mysql via ajax (Jquery)?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

How to pass values of multiple checkboxes to mysql via ajax (Jquery) dinamically, I mean that initially I do not know how many checkboxes will be chosen.

For example,I have to SELECT cars from db according to chosen colors (red, green), but after I desided to choose black color. web page should show me result of red,green,and black cars. how can I do it?

any ideas?

my code(but it can choose only one item)

```
<form>
          <div class="checkbox" >
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="item">Red</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="2" class="item">Green</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="4" class="item">Black</label>
          </div>
</form>



<script>
$(document).ready(function () {


    $('.item').change(function(){

            if($(this).is(':checked')){

                var name = $(this).val();
                $.post('load.php', {name:name}, function(data){
                    $('#name-data').html(data);
                });
            }
    });
});

</script>
```

php file with mysql query

```
   <?php 
   //1.Create a db connection
   define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
   define("DB_USER", "pavel");
     define("DB_PASS", "2601532");
    define("DB_NAME", "testik");

   $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
  //Test if connection succed
  if(mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
die("Database connection failed: ".
    mysqli_connect_error().
    "(" . mysqli_connect_errno(). ")"
);
}

 $Query = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE id ='".trim($_POST['name'])."'";
  $QueryResult = mysqli_query($connection , $Query);
   $QueryRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($QueryResult);

  ?>
            <div>
                <p><?php echo $QueryRow['cost']; ?></p>
                <img src="<?php echo $QueryRow['img']; ?>">
            </div>
```

Comment: Create an array of the selected values using `map()` (as per the duplicate I linked to) and send them in your AJAX request

Comment: Cam you write example usin my code?